# Dynamic API swagger schema without app restart

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to find a way to have the API swagger schema in the UI for a user change based on what "rows" they are allowed to see. For example... user1 is allowed to see "id", "first_name", "last_name", and "building_num". So the API schema would look like this:
[user 1 schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBafq.png)

Now, lets say user2 is using the API, and they are allowed to see "id", "first_name", "last_name", but not building_num. We would want the schema to show this when visiting the doc page:

[user2 schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92AmZ.png)

The problem is it seems once the API is started, the schema is generated and is not able to change when setting the response_model in the FastAPI GET decorator.

here is the code I have:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
import os
import json

app = FastAPI()

data = [(123, "John", "Smith", 16)]

def make_model():
 
    Get the allowed rows the user accessing the API is allowed to see,
    and create a model based off of that.
    """
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    fp = os.path.join(script_dir, 'allowed.json')
    with open(fp, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    

    allowed_rows = data['allowed_rows']

    fields_for_model = {}

    for field in allowed_rows:
        fields_for_model[field] = (str, None)

    model = create_model("user", **fields_for_model)
    return model


@app.get("/user", response_model=make_model())
async def fetch_user():

    # all fields present in database. If any are not in the allowed rows,
    # then they will not be added to the model created.
    all_fields = (
        ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'building_num'])


    model = make_model()

    for i in data:
        dict_of_data = dict(zip(all_fields, i))

        user = model(**dict_of_data)

    return user
```

The allowed.json file is set up like this:

```
{
    "allowed_rows": [
        "id", "first_name", "last_name", "building_num"
    ]
}
```

To simulate grabbing information of what the current user of the API is allowed to see, we can remove any of these fields in the json file without restarting the app.

I am creating a dynamic user model for every request, based on the allowed rows found in a json file (to simulate an API call getting what the user is allowed to see for now).

Building the dynamic return model of "user" works, and when response_model is not set in the decorator, only the specified fields in the json file are shown/used to build the return model. We can remove fields from the json file without restarting the app and have the correct model built. However, when response_model is set, changing the json file does not change the "user" schema in the docs page.

Is there a way to have a dynamic API schema based on what the current user of the API is allowed to see? Any way to re-generate the schema instead of it being static and set when the API is first started?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this